# Joda time convert query

Tags: java, jodatime

How to convert from "2014-06-16T07:00:00.000Z" to "16-JUN-14 07:00:00" using joda time API?

The below code is throwing the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: T
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.parsePatternTo(DateTimeFormat.java:570)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.createFormatterForPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:693)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:181)
    at com.joda.JodaTimeTest.convertJodaTimezone(JodaTimeTest.java:59)
    at com.joda.JodaTimeTest.main(JodaTimeTest.java:50)
```

This is the code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(dstDateTime.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to enclose the literal `T` within single quotes. Also the milliseconds are not properly patterned. You need to include `SSS` for the milliseconds. Have a look at the [patterns here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

**Update:** To format the `DateTime` into a String representation of your choice, you need to do this.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(dstDateTime.toString()); // You get a DateTime object

// Create a new formatter with the pattern you want
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss");
String dateStringInYourFormat = formatter2.print(dt); // format the DateTime to that pattern
System.out.println(dateStringInYourFormat); // Prints 16-Jun-14 12:30:00 because of the TimeZone I'm in
```

Either specify the timezone yourself or your default system timezone would be taken.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but getting this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-06-16T07:00:00.000Z" is malformed at ".000Z"

Comment: Now it is working fine, but small issue, the output is adding the "-07:00" at the end 2014-06-16T00:00:00.000-07:00, which i dont need it. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
```

To

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"
```

Now

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-06-16T07:00:00.000Z");
System.out.println(dt);
```

Output:

```
2014-06-16T07:00:00.000+05:30
```

Comment: Thank you for the update, but getting this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-06-16T07:00:00.000Z" is malformed at ".000Z"